# how to use RegisterPropertyEditor

Tags: delphi, custom-component

I created a component that had a (data source) and a (data field) Property  as same as TDBLookupComboBox.
but now I need more than one (data field) Property by different names. 
I know that I should to use RegisterPropertyEditor() but i don't know how? 
here is my code
what should i do?

```
  TMyComp = class(TPanel)
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FDataSource:TDataSource;
    FDataField:String;
    FDataField1:String;
  protected
    { Protected declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  published
    { Published declarations }
    Property DataSource: TDataSource Read FDataSource Write FDataSource;
    Property DataField: String Read FDataField Write FDataField;
    Property DataField1: String Read FDataField1 Write FDataField1;
  end;

procedure Register;

implementation

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('Samples', [TMyComp]);
  RegisterPropertyEditor(TypeInfo(string), ????, 'DataField1', ?????);
end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need to separate your component code from your registration code and place them in separate runtime and designtime packages, respectively, where the designtime package *Requires* your runtime package, and the `dcldb` and `DesignIDE` packages.

Then, you can write the code like this:

Runtime-time:

```
unit MyRunTimeUnit;

interface

uses
  ...;

type
  TMyComp = class(TPanel)
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FDataSource: TDataSource;
    FDataField: String;
    FDataField1: String;
  protected
    { Protected declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  published
    { Published declarations }
    Property DataSource: TDataSource Read FDataSource Write FDataSource;
    Property DataField: String Read FDataField Write FDataField;
    Property DataField1: String Read FDataField1 Write FDataField1;
  end;

implementation

...

end.
```

Design-time:

```
unit MyDesigTimeUnit;

interface 

procedure Register;

implementation

uses
  DBReg, MyRunTimeUnit;

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('Samples', [TMyComp]);
  RegisterPropertyEditor(TypeInfo(String), TMyComp, 'DataField1', TDataFieldProperty);
end;
```

Then you can install your design-time package into the IDE.

Comment: or nil for global

Comment: @user2995801 what are you referring to?

Comment: If you specify nil instead of a component (TMyComp), it will be valid globally for all fields of this type.

Comment: @user2995801 technically yes, but that's not desirable in this case since the editor is being registered for `String`. You don't want to replace the default editor for all `String` properties globally